# How to convert INDIAN currency to double?

Tags: java, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I want to convert Indian Currency into double. Below is my code:

```
String initalAmount = "2341";
Format format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
String convertedAmountToINR = format.format(new BigDecimal(initalAmount));
// it prints Rs. 2,341.00
```

Now, I want to convert it into DOUBLE like **2341.00**. I tried couple of ways to get it worked but didn't.

Comment: Why don't you store the new BigDecimal value and use that? This looks like homework to me.

Comment: You can convert it to a double with `Double d = Double.parseDouble(initalAmount);` but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: [Dont use `double` for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
double doubleINR=Double.parseDouble(convertedAmountToINR);
```

For your case try following,

```
  double d=Double.parseDouble(convertedAmountToINR.replaceAll("Rs.|,", ""));
```

Comment: Great answer. It worked for me. Better if you provide a little description for used regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert initialAmount to a double like this:

```
Double.valueOf(initalAmount);
```

The reason why you can't convert `convertedAmountToINR` is because the "Rs." in it can't be converted into a double.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can convert the `convertedAmountToINR` back with the same `format` object:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
double value = format.parse(convertedAmountToINR).doubleValue();
```

This will only parse strings that were formatted with this format object.